# Sync the Windows 10 recycle bin

Tags: windows-10, sync, recycle-bin, cloud-storage

I've been increasingly regarding my main computer and various laptops as a single machine, since relying more heavily on cloud storage for my most common data. One area of improvement would be syncing the Windows 10 recycle bin across multiple computers.

Is there a way to change the various recycle bin locations across drives (eg `C:\$Recycle.Bin`) to a cloud storage folder, using the registry or otherwise? An example with Google Drive would be to change `C:\$Recycle.Bin` to `C:\Users\Username\My Drive\recycle bins\$Recycle.Bin`.

Can anyone advise the technical feasibility of this? It would be convenient to stop considering the contents of the recycle bin on an individual computer basis.

Comment: The recycle bin is most definitely not a storage location and was never designed to be such (I keep mine empty).  Syncing to garbage can across machines strikes me as not doable and not necessary.

Comment: “Can anyone advise the technical feasibility of this?”- Zero, as your attempting to do something that isn’t possible, and isn’t technically feasible